# Angular Mock Test - Async call of service

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Have an issue with the code where i try to check the DOM element..Have used an ngIf with a service async call in HTML and sample code is as below:

```html
<div class="" *ngIf="EmployeeService.employees$ | async">
 <div class="header-right-content">
                    <span class="settings-label">Employee Status: </span>
                        <custom-element>{{(EmployeeService.employees$ | async)?.EmployeeStatus}}</custom-element>
                        

</div>
```

My Service is as below:

```js
export class EmployeeService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private errorHandlerService: ErrorHandlerService) { }
    employees$: BehaviorSubject<Client[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  getEmployeeList() {
        //make http call to controller
        this.url = `---------`;
        this.busySubscription =
            this.http.post(this.url, filters)
                .subscribe((employees) => {
                    this.employees$.next(employees["Employees"]);
                    this.recordCount = employees["TotalRows"];
                },
                    error => {
                        this.employees$.next(null);
                        this.errorHandlerService.handleError(error);
                    });
    }
}
```

In my Unit test is like below:

```js
 it('should Create UI element', (done) => { 
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            let uiElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('custom-element');        
            expect(uiElement.length).toBe(1);
            done();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="" *ngIf="(employeeService.employees$ | async).length">
 <div class="header-right-content">
     <span class="settings-label">Employee Status: </span>
       <custom-element *ngFor="let employee of (employeeService.employees$ | async)">{{employee.EmployeeStatus}}</custom-element>
</div>
```

Try like this, your 'employees' is Array. So you should work with that like you work with Array
In component where you use Employee service dont forget to inject EmployeeService

```
constructor(public employeeService:EmployeeService){}
```

Anyway, unit tests which you provided will fail

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
const mockedEmployees = [1,2,3];
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ <YourComponent>],
      providers: [{provide:EmployeeSercvice, useValue: {
employees$:of(mockedEmployees)
}]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BaseEditWidgetComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
      it('should have 3 employees', () => {
     component.employeeService.employees$.subscribe(employees=>{
 expect(employees.length).toBe(3)
done();
})         
  });
```

Something like this.

Comment: Thanks Danil for the quick response....The service was already injected to the component. However getting issue at component.employeeService.employees$.subscribe(employees=>{
 expect(employees.length).toBe(3)...meaning it is unable to subscribe the service ...service not found....Could you help me with this pls...Thanks